# High-level / semantic UITextField setup

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I feel that configuring `UITextField`s is more work than it should be. The App I'm currently working on has a small number of text field needs:

- Email input – never correct and uses the email keyboard.
- Password input – never corrects, uses the standard keyboard, obscures entry.
- Title text – corrects, uses standard keyboard, capitalises first letters.
- Other text – corrects, uses standard keyboard, capitalises first letter of a sentence.

… and that's mostly it.

So, instead of:

```
[self.txfPassword setSecureTextEntry: YES];
[self.txfPassword setAutocorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[self.txfPassword setAutocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[self.txfPassword setSpellCheckingType: UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo];
[self.txfPassword setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
```

I'd like to do:

```
[self.txfPassword setPurpose: UITextFieldPurposePassword];
```

Is there **some kind of built in thing** that does that, or am I going to be rolling my own?

Ideally, this would be built in so that:

- When iOS sees I'm working with, say, an email address, it'll offer to insert emails from the address book, and could also perform the correct validation too.
- Or a twitter handle / FB identity will provide for searching in my friends, and then in other publicly known identities.
- Or if I'm using a password, it'll offer to generate a random string and slap it in the keychain.
- Or if it's a phone number, it can look that up in the address book, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you need to use category or subclass for `UITextField`. And many more helper class that can do the hidden functionality and only return desire result to show when textfield input is there.

Comment: *nods* That's kind of what I'm expecting – I'm just a bit boggled that this isn't a built in thing to some degree, or that there isn't a known good library that does it.

Comment: I just hope that some one does swim so far.

Comment: Quite a lot of S.O. Q&A in this area. I think an object that configures the text fields given a semantic description, and then acts as a delegate for them would work well. It could provide validation, next responder behaviour, pressing buttons after complete input, and probably even neat stuff like email / twitter lookup.

Comment: Any comment on my answer? Not heard anything good or bad and not been accepted either. Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily create a category for this sort of thing...

```
// .h
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TextFieldPurpose) {
    TextFieldPurposePassword,
    TextFieldPurposeEmail,
    TextFieldPurposeBlah,
};

@interface UITextField (Purpose)

- (void)setPurpose:(TextFieldPurpose)purpose;

@end

// .m
@implementation UITextField (Purpose)

- (void)setPurpose:(TextFieldPurpose)purpose
{
    switch(purpose) {
        case TextFieldPurposePassword:
            [self setPasswordPurpose];
            break;
        case TextFieldPurposeEmail:
            [self setEmailPurpose];
            break;
        case TextFieldPurposeBlah:
            // set some other purpose
            break;
    }
}

- (void)setEmailPurpose
{
    // do your email set up here...
}

- (void)setPasswordPurpose
{
    [self setSecureTextEntry: YES];
    [self setAutocorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    [self setAutocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [self setSpellCheckingType: UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo];
    [self setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
}

@end
```

Now instead of doing all that config on your textfield you just have to `#import UITextField+Purpose.h"` and then...

```
[self.txfPassword setPurpose:TextFieldPurposePassword];
```

Comment: Hiya. Thank you for the answer. I gave you an upvote but I've left it open for a while as I'd like to see if any other suggestions come through (particularly for a library that provides some of the additional points I was hoping for). For just the initial requirements in the question a category is a good solution. I ended up implementing a manager for a set of text fields (for correct return key behaviour and such), that also provides the semantic set up and validation based on the usage semantics too.